# Practice question for Security+ that I think is wrong. Integrity vs availability

Tags: integrity, certification, availability

There is the following question on a practice test:

> Which service are you addressing by installing a RAID array and load
>   balancer?
>
> A. Confidentiality
>
> B. Availability
>
> C. Accountability
>
> D. Integrity

The correct answer according to practice test is "Integrity".

Can someone explain this and why it would not be "Availability"? I'm not understanding how availability wouldn't be the correct choice.

Comment: A raid array allows one or more drives to go bad without losing the data.  So it preserves the integrity of the data.

Comment: I don't think "Availability" is a wrong answer, though.  Seems just as valid.

Comment: @pcalkins: I also think that availability is also addressed. If one of drives fails, it can be swapped without shutting down the whole system. This improves the availability.

Comment: With most of these certifications, right and wrong are irrelevant. As best you can, give them the answer they want in order to pass the test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By combining RAID with a load balancer, the question is asking about "Availability".

**This appears to be a mistake in the answer.** I doubt very much that CompTIA expects that "Integrity" is the intended answer.

I have taken over a couple of dozen certification exams and thousands of practice questions. It is very, very common for there to be mistakes. Your best response is to do what you've done: understand ***why*** the answer is the answer and not just memorise the answers.